# Can you set ValueCount() to output the corresponding entry as well as the value count?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Say you have the following data frame and you needed to know how many Assays were done per month.

```
type,"Date Tested"
Assay,2022/01/28
Assay,2022/01/31
Assay,2022/02/02
Assay,2022/03/31
Assay,2022/04/21
Assay,2022/05/12
Assay,2022/06/02
Assay,2022/02/03
Assay,2022/06/03
```

You can use value_counts() from Pandas to easily do this.

```
data['Date Tested']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date Tested'], format = "%Y/%m/%d")
months = data['Date Tested'].dt.month.value_counts(sort=False)
print(months)
```

Which outputs:

```
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
Name: Date Tested, dtype: int64
```

The 'numbers' in the first column are each month (i.e 01 - Jan, 02 - Feb etc..) but this isn't great. What if the dataset started at March? Then March = 01.
Or what if I needed to do the same thing but by weeks? How could you workout what, say 12 was in terms of a week?

How can you modify the output of value_count to include the corresponding month/week? This information is present in the dataframe, shown by:

```
print(data['Date Tested'])
```

Which gives:

```
0   2022-01-28
1   2022-01-31
2   2022-02-02
3   2022-03-31
4   2022-04-21
5   2022-05-12
6   2022-06-02
7   2022-02-03
8   2022-06-03
Name: Date Tested, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Ideally, my count output would be something like this:

```
2022-01   2
2022-02   2
2022-03   1
2022-04   1
2022-05   1
2022-06   2
Name: Date Tested, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) (`M` = monthly) and count:

```
data.groupby(data['Date Tested'].dt.to_period('M'))['type'].count()
```

output:

```
Date Tested
2022-01    2
2022-02    2
2022-03    1
2022-04    1
2022-05    1
2022-06    2
Freq: M, Name: type, dtype: int64
```

By week:

```
data.groupby(data['Date Tested'].dt.to_period('W'))['type'].count()
```

output:

```
Date Tested
2022-01-24/2022-01-30    1
2022-01-31/2022-02-06    3
2022-03-28/2022-04-03    1
2022-04-18/2022-04-24    1
2022-05-09/2022-05-15    1
2022-05-30/2022-06-05    2
Freq: W-SUN, Name: type, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of indexes

```
>>> df.set_index(df['Date Tested'].dt.month)['Date Tested']\
      .groupby(level=0)\
      .count()

Date Tested
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
```

where here, the indexes are guaranteed to be the corresponding month of the year. For example, if you remove the first two rows of your `df` where the month is January, the output is

```
Date Tested
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
```

Answer (score 0):

grouupby date as strftime format Year-Month and count or find size

```
df.groupby(df['DateTested'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).agg('size').to_frame('count')

    

               count
DateTested       
2022-01         2
2022-02         2
2022-03         1
2022-04         1
2022-05         1
2022-06         2
```